# unable to install ipython on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, ipython

am using Mac El Capitan, I need to install iPython and have to use iPython notebook

I use

```
$ pip install ipython
```

to install the ipython, but it return me

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pickleshare in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gnureadline in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): appnope in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pexpect in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): path.py in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pickleshare->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ptyprocess>=0.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pexpect->ipython)

abhi ~ $ ipython
-bash: ipython: command not found
```

any idea what am doing wrong, or what should I do now?

I tried this on my IDLE

```
>>> try:
    import ipython
    print "imported"
except :
    print "not installed"
```

> > it says not installed.

Comment: ipython is not a bash command. Enter the python console and you should be able to import ipython.

Comment: @ChaiNunes I have edited the question at the bottom. what should I do now? any clue, am just getting directionless

Comment: same issue in macOS Sierra

Answer (score 3):

Try this command:

```
python -m IPython
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), a Python distribution that includes most of the Python packages for science, maths, engineering, and data analysis. This is arguably the easiest way to get up and running with iPython (now Jupyter) notebooks.

Comment: ok, but I have already installed almost every other package like science, maths etc.
wont installing anaconda effect it?

Comment: No, I believe it should import over the top of any existing packages you already have. It's a very robust installation process.

Comment: are you using the anaconda? are you using it for data mining and other stuff? ipython notebook works perfectly?

Comment: Yes, I use it everyday at work and home for that kind of thing. iPython notebooks run perfectly through Anaconda - it is the simplest, least troublesome way of using the notebooks.

Comment: I will do the same. I heard about anaconda from other classmates too. I will give a try to it now, other than installing different packages.

Comment: Good luck! If it works for you feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: what is the difference between the GUI installer and commandline installer. are both different? or I need to install both of them

Comment: oops i installed through gui and cmd installer both, and now in my home directory its showing anaconda, and anaconda 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100877/discussion-between-jonathan-and-jeev).

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issues when trying to install ipython and jupyter on my mac (El Capitan v10.11.6)

Tried various combinations including `sudo -H`, `--ignore <whatever people suggested>` etc.

The only thing that worked for me:

```
pip install --user ipython
pip install --user jupyter
```

You would also need to add your 'user python modules' to your path. One way is using nano to edit your .bash_profile:

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/YOUR USER ID/Library/Python/2.7/bin

Then just open a new terminal or use `source` command to apply it in the open terminal.

You can find a different approach [here](http://www.caban.me/2016/02/10/ipython-on-osx-el-capitan/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't have `bin` in `Python/2.7`, I only got `lib`

Comment: Have you installed the libraries? If you answer 'yes' and don't have a bin folder - do you have ipython and jupyter in your bin? You could create a bin folder as the above path is yours (it is under your user id) and try to re-install.